# How to make JIRA issue key to be case insensitive when integrates with gitlab

Tags: gitlab, jira

I have GitLab CE integrates with JIRA. When I commit a comment like "ABC-123 summary" it will add a comment into the JIRA issue (ABC-123).

However, if the issue key in GitLab comment is in lower case (e.g. "abc-123 summary"), it fails to add the comment.

How can I make it be case insensitive, so that "ABC-123", "abc-123", "Abc-123" also work?

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/jira.html) does not seem to support case-insensitive match, possibly because the [Jira project key is always uppercase](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-24675)

If the GitLab-Jira integration calls the Jira API, [`GET /rest/api/3/project/{projectIdOrKey}`](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-rest-api-3-project-projectIdOrKey-get), its project Id or Key is case sensitive.

The plugin might have chosen the approach of "not guessing if  "abc-123", "Abc-123" are actual Jira project, and only detect uppercase ones.